Runaway argument: ! Paragraph ended before \\customcventry was complete. <to be read again> \par
I'm trying to figure out how to fix the bugs in my code in overleaf so I can submit and have an actual copy of my resume. In order to do so, I kinda need to fix the bugs which is hard considering how I don't know much about coding let alone LaTeX.
This is the error:
! Paragraph ended before \\customcventry was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.73

This is the other error:
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.81 

This is the FULL code:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=0.915]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\name{Leonard}{Way}
\newcommand*{\customcventry}[7][.13em]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
{\bfseries #4} \
{\itshape #3}
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
{\bfseries #5} \
{\itshape #2}
\end{tabular}
\ifx&#7&%
\else{\
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
\small#7%
\end{minipage}}\fi%
\par\addvspace{#1}}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-16mm}
\begin{center}\textbf{High School Student at Westview High School}\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
\faMobile\enspace +1 8584284764 & \enspace lway123666@gmail.com & \faHome\enspace San Diego, California \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{Profile}
{Resourceful and dedicated High School Student with strong management skills, Bringing forth excellent management abilities, multitasking skills, and the drive to motivation to help fellow peers. Adept at working well with others and committing myself as a positive team player.}


\section{Education}
\customcventry{2022-Present}{\color{blue}\href{https://westview.powayusd.com/}{Westview High School}}{High School Student}{San Diego, CA}{}{}{Currently Enrolled: Psychology, Calculus AB, Chinese}
\section{Professional Experience}
\customcventry{08/2021 ‐ present}{{\color{blue}\href{https://www.maranathachapel.org/awana}{(Awana)}}}{Awana Leader}{San Diego, CA}{}{
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.6cm, label={\textbullet}]
\item Teach kids about the Gospel every week
\item Supervise all children to ensure their safety 
\item Recognized by peers as well as adult leaders as one of the most esteemed leaders
\item Help cultivate the next generation of followers under Christ
\end{itemize}}}

\customcventry{01/2023 ‐ 05/2023}{{\color{blue}\href{https://www.maranathachapel.org/vbs}{(VBS)}}}{Color Team Leader,}{San Diego, CA}{}{
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.6cm, label={\textbullet}]
\item Oversee a group of children yearly to teach them about the Gospel of Christ
\item Monitored all my students in order to make sure they understood the curriculum as well as could explain it themselves
\item Fostered community as well a sense of belonging within all of my students giving them an unforgettable experience
\end{itemize}}}

\customcventry{09/2023 ‐ Present}{{\color{blue}\href{https://matchbox.lol/}{(Matchbox)}}}{Ambassador at Matchbox}{San Diego, CA}{}{
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.6cm, label={\textbullet}]
\item Founded the first branch of an app in San Diego 
\item Garnered over 100 users on the first week and more than 700 followers for the app the week after
\item Maintained consistent activity on the account with weekly stories 
\item Recognized for my reliability and being able to manage an app which I helped customize personally for my school.
\end{itemize}}}

\customcventry{06/2021 ‐ 12/2021}
\section{Extracurricular Activities}

\customcventry{01/2021 ‐ Present}{Badminton}{
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.6cm, label={\textbullet}]
\item Trained by a world champion 
\item Made varsity team freshman year
\item Competed in an international tournament 
\item Trained select people and got them on the team
\end{itemize}}}

\customcventry{01/2019 ‐ 01/2021}{{\color{blue}\href{http://www.smashbsd.com/}{(SMASH! Badminton)}}}{Badminton}{San Diego, CA}{}{
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.6cm, label={\textbullet}] 
\item Made the varsity team freshman year
\item Trained select people to help them get on the team
\item Participated in an international tournament
\end{itemize}}}

\customcventry{08/2022 ‐ Present}{{{Westview Gold}}}{Competitive Marching Band}{San Diego, CA}{}{
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.6cm, label={\textbullet}]
\item Played the trumpet and horn for 5+ years
\item Helped guide numerous freshman on how to play their instrument correctly 
\end{itemize}}}

\section{Skills}
{\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item {\textbf{Computer Programming:} Able to code in: C++, LUA, Python, Java. Competed in code forces competitions as well as done numerous problems in USACO and Leetcode}

\item {\textbf{Game Development} Roblox, Godot, Unity, Blender}

\end{itemize}}

\section{Languages}
{\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item {\textbf{Chinese:} Fluent}

\item {\textbf{English} Fluent}

\end{itemize}}
\end{document}



We'll need to know what \documentclass you're using.  Would you be able to have a complete example with that and what you have here and maybe 5 more lines of code?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Where does come the command \customcventry. Could you edit your answer to provide a minimal working example (MWE)?

Hey Teepeemm I added all the code for better context

Sorry jlab, I don't really know how to provide a MWE so I just put all the code down. Sorry but I don't really know much about this language besides how to make sections items, and some other small stuff

Why do you have backslashes at the end of lines? Don't do that. Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

\newcommand*{\customcventry}[7][.13em] means a command with 6 mandatory arguments (typically the groups between {...}) and 1 optional one (between [...]). They're missing in the sections Extracurricular Activities and after. Maybe you should try something else, like moderncv.

Thank you jlab and cfr, I never realized there was a part of the code that never showed up. It turns out I kind of forgot about it and worked around it. Thank you so much again!
